# USA FEMA Flood Zone Polygons and Metadata

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for the FEMA flood zone GIS files.  The [portal](http://msc.fema.gov/portal/#) lets you look at a single address but I would like to get for each zone its geographic polygon and related FEMA metadata.

It appears from the portal that each zone is subdivided into smaller grids. It would be great if I could get this as well.

Comment: Do you have any specific area you want to look at ?

Comment: https://msc.fema.gov/portal/resources/faq "Using Our Products" question 4 "Is there a direct download option available for flood hazard products?" may help, as may question 11 under "Locating Our Products": "How do I locate modeling and other backup data used to recreate the maps?". You could also try contacting FEMA directly or scraping data from their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can download the shapefile for the National Flood Hazard Layer from data.gov:

http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/national-flood-hazard-layer-nfhle9690

Answer (score 2):

how about ESRI Open data and you just type it where you are looking for a specific area. What is so nice about it that it has a filter that you can narrow down to your specific area and you can download if you have your ESRI account. I just did on mine for Colorado.

http://opendata.arcgis.com/